# I've come in many colors

Tags: riddle

I've come in many colors,
   browns and blues and greens.

I've been east, I've been west,
   And most everywhere between.

One could say I've given life,
   And in a sense that's true.

Yet I'm no saint, let's be clear,
   I have the power to end life, too.

You see me almost every day,
   Though sometimes with just a glance.

I can make you rather cool,
   If you'd only give me a chance.

To me, there should be only one answer, but I'm not sure if anything else could fit this mold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> Water?

I've come in many colors,
browns and blues and greens.

> Generally thought of as blue, but some beaches have a greenish tint to the water. Muddy or dirty water is brown.

I've been east, I've been west,
And most everywhere between.

> East coast, west coast, rivers, lakes, etc.

One could say I've given life,
And in a sense that's true.

> Can't live without water.  Also, (as proposed by ace), could be thinking of evolution and came from the water.

Yet I'm no saint, let's be clear,
I have the power to end life, too.

> Drowning, storms, etc.

You see me almost every day,
Though sometimes with just a glance.

> Water is everywhere, but we don't always look at it. Rain maybe, or watering of grass.

I can make you rather cool,
If you'd only give me a chance.

> Swimming is generally an activity when it is really hot.

Comment: Argh... I registered an account just to answer this question, and just as I was typing my answer you already answered it...

Comment: @ace I've seen some answers posted within 10 seconds of each other.

Comment: By the way for the giving life part I was thinking about [this](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/_9LQDdY9HRcY/TTys7CCNfdI/AAAAAAAAAA8/5oRf_Onm8KU/s1600/2000px-Darwin_fish_ROF.svg.png). (Spoiler alert)

Comment: That would be it.

Comment: @ace That was what I was thinking for the giving life.

Comment: @tfitzger Is the "let's be clear" intended or did I over-interpret it?

Comment: @ace The` let's be clear` was more fluff than anything.

Answer (score 6):

I say:

> Trees

I've come in many colors,
browns and blues and greens.

> Typical colors for trees

I've been east, I've been west,
And most everywhere between.

> There are trees almost everywhere on the globe, Deserts and the polar caps being the exception

One could say I've given life,
And in a sense that's true.

> Trees/Forests harbor life and create oxygen so in a way we would die without them and the resources they provide for us as well as being for smaller creatures their own ecosystem

Yet I'm no saint, let's be clear,
I have the power to end life, too.

> Forest Fires, Trees shed their leaves in fall *killing* them, If a tree falls on you... you'll be squashed (lumberjacks have died from being squashed by big trees.) And some movies even go and ridiculously claim that trees can mentally control you to kill yourself. (*cough cough the happening*)

You see me almost every day,
Though sometimes with just a glance.

> In most places on the planet you do see trees every single day, but we are so used to them that we don't really pay them attention (especially in cities)

I can make you rather cool,
If you'd only give me a chance.

> Trees also provide shade. Which is awesome on lunch breaks and etc... So next time you eat lunch at work, step outside for a sec and find yourself a tree. Be hippie , uh wait! I mean happy.

Comment: I like your way of thinking. I'm trying to think of when I've seen blue trees, however...

Comment: I somehow missed that one color >_<       I guess some *plants* are blue. And some coral can definitely be blue too but that's a stretch.

Comment: @tfitzger, blue spruce.

Comment: @tfitzger - (hildred just beat me to blue spruce), also Blue Gum (eucalyptus), and this http://www.kondimopoulos.com/thebluetrees/about/

Answer (score 3):

The answer's already been given, but I thought I'd come up with an alternative idea:

> Birds.

I've come in many colors,
browns and blues and greens.

> Yup.

I've been east, I've been west,
And most everywhere between.

> Birds are everywhere and are notorious for their migration patterns.

One could say I've given life,
And in a sense that's true.

> Chicken $\rightarrow$ Egg (or was it the other way around?)

Yet I'm no saint, let's be clear,
I have the power to end life, too.

> [image]

You see me almost every day,
Though sometimes with just a glance.

> This likely depends on geography, but it's certainly possible to see, and yet barely notice, birds daily.  This is probably the weakest link.

I can make you rather cool,
If you'd only give me a chance.

> [image]
>
> Now tell me that ain't cool...

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer:

> The Earth? From space, Earth looks to be a combination of brown, blue, and green (ignoring clouds). It is concurrently east west and everything between. It's given life by existing. It can also create a natural disaster. Bare patches of earth are rarely seen in urban areas and even more frequently seen elsewhere. Also, I assume the last line references global warming?

I was considering breaking up my reasoning but this is clearer imo.

Comment: This is an interesting guess, but not quite there.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> The sun?

I've come in many colors,
browns and blues and greens

> The light that comes from the sun is made of many colors

I've been east, I've been west,
And most everywhere between.

> the sun rises in the east and set in the west

One could say I've given life,
And in a sense that's true.

> Without the sun, no life

Yet I'm no saint, let's be clear,
I have the power to end life, too.

> If you're too close from the sun, or if it's too hot, you can die

You see me almost every day,
Though sometimes with just a glance.

> We see the sun every day but sometimes it's hide by the clouds

I can make you rather cool,
If you'd only give me a chance.

> I don't know for this one. Maybe something about the shadow or you're just cool with sunglasses...

Comment: Not quite, but I like your thinking.